# WHILE and FOR loop optimisation in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, while-loop

I have a database of sales, each sale has a customer id number, which might appear several times if the customer has more than one transaction.

I want to be able to see how many times each customer has participated in a sale up to the moment of the transaction, for instance:

```
customer X has 3 transactions
TRANSACTION 1 ON 04/17
TRANSACTION 2 ON 02/17
TRANSACTION 1 ON 11/16
```

I want to see previous transactions of this customer in the previous 4 months to the particular transaction, so I want to have something like this

```
customer X has 3 transactions
TRANSACTION 1 ON 04/17 - 1 previous transaction (transaction 1 doesn't count bc it is older than 4 months)
TRANSACTION 2 ON 02/17 - 1 previous transaction
TRANSACTION 1 ON 11/16 - 0 previous transactions
```

My code is

```
for(i in 1:length(db$CUSTOMERID)){
   j<-i+1
   while(db$CUSTOMERID[i]==db$CUSTOMERID[j]){
    if((db$date[i]-db$date[j])>0 & (db$date[i]-db$date[j])<120){
      db$PREVIOUSTRANSACTIONS[i] <- 1+ 
    db$PREVIOUSTRANSACTIONS[i]}else{db$PREVIOUSTRANSACTIONS[i]
        j<-j+1
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `subset()`?

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend `foverlaps` function from `data.table` package.

It allows to do date range merges without loops:

```
dt <- data.table(
  customer.id = c("X", "X", "X"),
  transaction.id = c(3L, 2L, 1L), 
  date = as.Date(c("2017-04-01", "2017-02-01", "2016-11-01"))
)

dt[, previos.range.start := date - 30.5 * 4]
dt[, previos.range.end := date]

dt.previous <- copy(dt)
dt[, date.copy := date]
setkeyv(dt.previous, c("previos.range.start", "previos.range.end"))

# join previous transactions to the dataset based using date ranges
res <- foverlaps(dt, dt.previous, by.x = c("date", "date.copy"), 
                 by.y = c("previos.range.start", "previos.range.end"))  
# aggregate back to transaction granularity level and calculate previous transactions metric
res <- res[order(transaction.id), .(
                previous.transactions = sum(ifelse(transaction.id == i.transaction.id, 0L, 1L)),
                date = min(date)
              ),  
              by = transaction.id]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly, but i dont really understand your code, would you mind explaining it a litte?

Comment: 1. for each transaction you need to identify period in which previous transactions will be counted. 2 you need to join dataset to self over transaction dates and peeiods from point 1. 3. aggregate back to the transaction level and count

Comment: also see data.table syntax here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf